# Android list with edit texts in Samsung

Tags: android

I am facing a problem with the samsung tablet that i have. I have an expandable list view, each child of the expandable list view contains edit texts. When i tap on any edit text which is at the bottom of the screen, the edit text is coming above the keyboard. Once I start typing the edit text goes back to its original position (at the bottom of the screen). The focus still remains in the field but I am not able to see what I am typing.

I get this in the log of the application when i face this problem.
"SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length "

I am not able to reproduce the problem in the other device which does not have TouchWiz installed.

here are the details of the samsung tablet i used.
Model Number - GT-P7510
Android version: 4.0.4
Kernal Version: 3.1.10
Build no: IMM76D.UELPL

Can you please provide a solution to the problem as i even tried changing the keyboard and that also did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this code in your `manifest.xml` for a particular activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**Note :**

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Comment: Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` instead of `adjustPan`

Comment: I have tried that as well. There were other issues when I tried that approach. i have uploaded the sample code. you can get it from this link. https://app.box.com/s/el0m3zan7o25pio0emkl

Comment: ALso please make sure you are testing in a device which has a rom with TouchWiz installed, as it works fine for other devices.